# Validate an object with Joi to only have specific keys

Tags: javascript, validation, hapi.js

I am validating a plain JavaScript object with `@hapi/joi` to have specific keys.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().min(5).max(30).required(),
  email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2 }).required(),
  subject: Joi.string().min(3).max(60).required(),
  message: Joi.string().min(24).required()
}).strict();
```

However, this setup allows other keys to be in the object to be validated. I want it to be valid ONLY if it has only the specified keys defined by the schema.

Comment: you mean if the input has `name1` key , it should throw error? just wanted to make sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only keys defined in schema are allowed.

Comment: what version of joi are you using? I tried using joi 17 and it works as expected.